# Turn simple query into a count case statement

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is quite helpful, that I would like help simplifying and turning into a count that I can add to a larger query that I'm working on. I have a scenario that occurs in my data where there are many to one relationships where there shouldn't be. Just to keep it simple, I'd describe it as if ford were describing all of the sedans they sold of a particular model, and in their data base they had more than one occurrence of a 'Red Sedan'. This causes problems for us, and I'd like to product a simple count of that occurrence in a larger query.

I have a query that successfully uncovers all cases of duplicates of 'red sedan' occurring (below)

```
select p.model, p.mFinish, count(p.productVendorStockNumber) as prodno, b.BrandName
from products p
join brands b on p.brandID = b.brandID 
where p.brandid = 299 and p.`status` = 1 and p.model != ''
GROUP BY p.model, p.mFinish
HAVING prodno > 1;
```

which produces an output something like this (did my best to reproduce it there - sorry)

```
|Model|Finish| Prod No| BrandName|
|12334|Red   |      2 | Santec
```

What I'd like to do though is have just the count, which in this case is 'prod no' come out in a case statement. I'm sort of a journeymen SQL guy so reducing an entire query into a count is something that is beyond me. I'm not even quite sure what to search for, I tried enclosing the entire query in "Count" and "Sum" on a lark and obviously that didn't work. When someone has a moment can they please provide a little insight into how something like that would be done?

I don't know if this is helpful or not, but the query I'm adding it to is below

```
select b.brandName, b.BrandCode, SUM(Case When p.IMAP > p.MSRP THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'MAP Greater Than MSRP', COUNT(DISTINCT(p.ProductVendorStockNumber)) as 'Total Products', MAX(dl.createDate) 'Most Recent Data Load', b.BrandStatus, b.datasource as 'Data Source', b.state as 'State', CASE WHEN dl.datanextConf = 1 THEN 'Confirmed' ELSE 'Not Confirmed' END AS 'Data Incoming?'
from products p
left join brands b on p.brandID = b.brandID
left join dataloads dl on b.brandID = dl.brandID
where p.status = 1 and b.brandID = 653
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but someone posted an answer and then the answer was deleted. I'm reposting what they provided.

```
SELECT
    b.brandName,
    b.BrandCode,
    SUM( CASE WHEN p.IMAP > p.MSRP THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS 'MAP Greater Than MSRP',
    COUNT( DISTINCT ( p.ProductVendorStockNumber ) ) AS 'Total Products',
    ROUND(COUNT( DISTINCT (p.ImageName) )/COUNT( DISTINCT ( p.ProductVendorStockNumber ) ),2) '% with images',
    MAX( dl.createDate ) 'Most Recent Data Load',
    b.BrandStatus,
    b.datasource AS 'Data Source',
    b.state AS 'State',
CASE

    WHEN dl.datanextConf = 1 THEN
    'Confirmed' ELSE 'Not Confirmed' 
    END AS 'Data Incoming?',
    (
    SELECT
        count( * ) 
    FROM
        products p2 
    WHERE
        p2.brandid = p.brandid 
        AND p2.model = p.model 
        AND p2.mFinish = p.mFinish 
        AND p2.`status` = p.`status` 
    ) AS 'Total Duplicate Finishes'
FROM
    products p
    LEFT JOIN brands b ON p.brandID = b.brandID
    LEFT JOIN dataloads dl ON b.brandID = dl.brandID 
WHERE
    p.STATUS = 1 
AND b.brandID = 286
```